# Cannot see wide pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

So i am new to the jquerymobile world.
I am trying to put a jquerywrapper around my users pages.
I have most of it working, but i am stuck where the page is wide and does not fit in the width of a mobile device and it seems to be a fixed wide and can not scroll

So i am looking for suggestions on the correct way to do this. 
The wide data/page CANNOT be changed.
Thanks for any help

some of the key elements::

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/inc/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">

<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c" >
   <div class="pagewithmenu" data-role="page" id="user-home" data-theme="d" data-url="user-home">
       <div  data-theme="b" data-role="header" style="text-align: center;" data-title="<?=$siteuser->fname?> <?=$siteuser->lname?>">
            <?=$siteuser->fname?> <?=$siteuser->lname?>
            <a  href="/" data-role="button" class="u-home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b" data-iconshadow="false" data-inline="true">Home</a>
       </div>

       <div id="mycontent" data-role="content" >
         <div class="article" style="ov">
             <!--
             ***** WIDE PAGE DATA HERE ***** 
             this is user generated code and can be anything
             for example this is one i am seeing the problem 
             -->
             <table width="663" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bordercolor="purple" border="5" background="http://www.unitnet.com/sboggs/picts//purple_star.jpg" height="497" class="c3">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                     some picts
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
         </div>    
         </div>    
       </div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the wide page data and the styles that are applied.